# trying to install ubuntu on another computer

Tags: installation

I am trying to install ubuntu on a windows xp cumputer that don't have all the drivers installed so I can't go to the internet with it. I am wanting to use my windows 7 desk top to burn a disk so I can put ubuntu on my old xp computer. Can you help and give me directions?

Answer (score 1):

Download the desired Ubuntu ISO 12.10 [32bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/quantal/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso) or [64bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/quantal/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.iso), or 13.04 [32bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/raring/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso) or [64bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/raring/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso), once it downloads, you can either burn it to a CD/DVD, or create a bootable USB.   You can use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create the bootable USB, or [Imgburn](http://www.imgburn.com/) to create the CD/DVD.

[image]

[image]

Once done go to you XP machine, and set the BIOS to boot from either the CD/DVD or USB.

Answer (score 0):

You can also burn the disk directly from Windows 7.

Right-click the downloaded ISO file, choose *Open with*, then *Windows Disk Image Burner*.

This may be the easiest method for you, but one con is that the Win burner does not let you set the burn rate to a low speed. Burning the image at a slow speed helps minimize the chance of errors.